# How do I build latest AOSP?

Tags: java, android, android-source

After configuring the AOSP fully. I tried to build it using **make -j4**. But I got the below error:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=IMM76
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
************************************************************
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: java version "1.7.0_55".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

It is trying to build 4.0.4, not the Android-L. Thats why it is asking for Java 6, because java 6 is needed for building 4.0.4.

How do I build for Android-L which can be build with Java-7? I want to contribute to AOSP. For which I only need latest AOSP master branch to be build not the older versions.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: so why dont you use v1.6?

Comment: @pskink Because I want Android-L to be build, not 4.0.4. Android-L can be build using v1.7. There was some problem while configuring which makes the build attempt with 4.0.4 not with Android-L.

Comment: If you want to build Android-L you must have its source code. Your AOSP code is ICS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you init your manifest on the incorrect version of AOSP. See [Downloading the Source](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) for a good explanation of what you need to do to setup AOSP.

The main part from there that you want though, is:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

Which would init your repository on AOSP version 4.0.1_r1. If you want to init on the l-preview branch, it would be:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b l-preview
```

Just keep in mind this isn't actually android l's source code, its a GPL update. I am not sure if they have moved it over to using java version 1.7 yet, as I have not personally tried.

Comment: I just want the master branch of AOSP. So I hope -b master will work fine.

Comment: If you just want master, you dont even need to specify master. As per the site, repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest defaults to master unless the -b parameter is specified.

Comment: Even I had the same assumption. But I don't know something is wrong. I tried that many times, but still it failed. git branch in "build" directory shows "no branch" and git log -1 shows a commit made in 2012. Moreover git describe shows android_4.0.4_r1

Comment: in .repo, look at manifests/default.xml. There should be an xml tag: <default revision="master". If it's not, as you say -b master should also work. If not, try again in a new directory perhaps. You may also want to bring it up on the repo google group if the default init is starting on 4.0.4

Comment: What exactly is the l-preview branch?  If it's not L's source code, where would you find that?  Master?

Comment: @GrandAdmiral you can't find it because it has not been released yet (as of the time of this comment). You probably wont see it until its released on a device, and then sometime within a few weeks after that